# How to disable loading screen tips?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to disable loading screen tips in StarCraft II, for example by editing the config file?

Comment: Are you asking for a custom map  you are making? Or the global variable for all SC2 load screens?

Comment: all loading screens (especially the ones on the ladder matchups)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not currently possible. You can remove them from custom maps by editing the map properties, though.

Answer (score 0):

"[Help Tab] on [Map] -> [Loading Screen] 
"If you want to remove this box, just set the Help section's text as a single space. "